# Irritating Python loop error?

Tags: python

ive been attempting this problem for a while and I cant seem to get the issue out.

```
listy2=['fun','super','Stop']
listy=['great','life','Stop','toys','nothing','Stop']
listpool=[listy,listy2]
current=[]
total=[]
nested=True
for i in listpool:
    for line in enumerate(i):
        if (line[0]==0):
            current.append(line[1])
            #skipping first line
            continue
        if (line[1].strip()!="") and (nested==True):
            current.append(line[1])
            nested=False
            continue
        if (line[1].strip()=="Stop"):
            nested=True
            continue
    total.append(current)
    #current[:] = []
print total
```

The program should output a list of lists. 
[[first element of list, nested things],[first element of list, nested things]]

Nested things are like:

```
hello
blah blah
Stop
```

the nested thing in this case would be hello
The lists can have multiple nested things.

```
cool
blah blah
Stop
good
blah blah
Stop
```

the nested thing in this example would be cool and good, (as you can tell, the things in the middle do no matter)

In my code it SHOULD output

```
[['fun','super'],['great','life','toys']]
```

however it does not.

Sorry if I cannot explain this question well, as English is not my first language but I am getting used to it. If you have any questions or comments please comment here. Sorry if I have done something stupid. It would also be nice if you could explain my error, but that would not be necessary.
Thanks.

Comment: Life will be easier if you write `for (n, line) in enumerate(i):`

Comment: Also, don't write `... and (nested == True):`; just write `... and nested:`.

Comment: I can't fathom the logic. Why should `'toys'` be in the output, but not `'nothing'`?

Comment: It is like programming almost, to only input the function name rather than what the function is doing

Comment: it is not nested, that is why nothing is not being outputted also.

Comment: In that case, why should `'super'` and `'life'` be in the output?

Comment: 'great' is the list name, so it is excluded.

Comment: the first element of listy and listy2 (everything in the listpool) is the name of the list

Comment: What do you mean `'great'` is excluded? It is listed in your expected output.

Comment: why did you comment out the line `current[:] = []` ?

Comment: I thought that it was the solution to my problem however it was just causing more troubles

Comment: 'great' is excluded from the nesting idea. But it is included in the first part of the list

Comment: @user1008537: I don't think that 'excluded' is the word you were looking for. @Marcelo Cantos: As far as I can tell, what is wanted is a collection of lists, where each (inner) list in the output contains the first line in the corresponding input file, and then the first line of each section, where sections are delimited by the special line 'stop', and may be followed by any number of blank lines. (The `strip` commands have led me to believe that the input is actually files, and not literal lists, as shown here)

Comment: yes, i have changed the example so people would not have to create files to run the program. I am just using lists as replacement for the lines in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand everything you're trying to do here, but the simplest answer is that you're not clearing the 'current' list in between outer loop iterations.

Try it like this:

```
listy2=['fun','super','Stop']
listy=['great','life','Stop','toys','nothing','Stop']
listpool=[listy,listy2]
total=[]
nested=True
for i in listpool:
    current=[]
    for line in enumerate(i):
        if (line[0]==0):
            current.append(line[1])
            #skipping first line
            continue
        if (line[1].strip()!="") and (nested==True):
            current.append(line[1])
            nested=False
            continue
        if (line[1].strip()=="Stop"):
            nested=True
            continue
    total.append(current)
print total
```

This is (slightly) more idiomatic python:

```
listy=['great','life','Stop','toys','nothing','Stop']
listy2=['fun','super','Stop']
listpool=[listy,listy2]

total=[]
for i in listpool:
    nested=True
    current=[]
    for (n, line) in enumerate(i):
        if (n==0):
            current.append(line) #skipping first line
        elif nested and line.strip():
            current.append(line)
            nested=False
        elif line.strip()=="Stop":
            nested=True
    total.append(current)
print total
```

Comment: Thanks, i looked back at what i have had previously done, and I realize that i error-ed in the scoping of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

You create *one* `current` list to which you append through all the iterations of your main loop. Probably you instead want to create a new `current` list in each iteration:

```
for i in listpool:
    current = []
    ...
    total.append(current)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've put the code that processes a single list into a function: I think this makes it easier to code, easier to test, and easier to understand. I found it difficult to give the function a good name because I don't really understand what the point of this code is, but this seems to do what you want.

```
def stop_words(words):
    # Have we ever seen the word 'Stop'?
    found_stop = False
    # Was the last word seen 'Stop'?
    last_stop = False
    for word in words:
        if word == 'Stop':
            found_stop = last_stop = True
            continue
        if not found_stop or last_stop:
            yield word
        last_stop = False

print [list(stop_words(words)) for words in [listy, listy2]]
```

You struggled to express clearly in English what you wanted the code to do, which hints to me that you'll struggle to express is clearly in code. I'd have said the code should extract every word before the first 'Stop' and only words following 'Stop' thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but this is what I gathered from the question.  You want a list containing sub-lists; each sub-list has the elements before the word "Stop".  If my interpretation is off, please let me know, but see if this works for what you need:

```
listy2 = ['fun','super','Stop']
listy = ['great','life','Stop','toys','nothing','Stop']
listpool = [listy,listy2]
total = []
for lst in listpool:
    current = []
    for line in lst:
        if line.strip() == "Stop":
            total.append(current)
            current = []
        else:
            current.append(line)
print total

[ 14:46 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/python ]$ ./irritating-python-loop-error.py 
[['great', 'life'], ['toys', 'nothing'], ['fun', 'super']]
```